# Having 10 random flash files from an array to display on a page when it loads all at once? (In javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, flash

I am making a flash gallery (Which I have gotten working correctly on the main page with an array of a thousand swf's files) and on a separate page you can visit I would like it if it would take 10 random flashs from that array and display all 10 at the same time video/audio so that it can be cancerous fun! Problem is I cant seem to get the flashs to display so I'm led to beleive that I'm missing something or something is in the wrong place. Please point me in the right direction or give me any tips for future use :D

HTML

```
<div class="titleText">
    <a href="index.html" class="downlink">
    <h1>Craz Page</h1>
        </a>
</div>

<div class="flashmoviecraz" id="flashmoviecraz1">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="">'+
        <param name="movie" value="">
    </object>
</div>
<div class="flashmoviecraz" id="flashmoviecraz2">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="">'+
        <param name="movie" value="">
    </object>
</div>
<div class="flashmoviecraz" id="flashmoviecraz3">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="">'+
        <param name="movie" value="">
    </object>
</div>
<div class="flashmoviecraz" id="flashmoviecraz4">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="">'+
        <param name="movie" value="">
    </object>
</div>
<div class="flashmoviecraz" id="flashmoviecraz5">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="">'+
        <param name="movie" value="">
    </object>
</div>
<div class="flashmoviecraz" id="flashmoviecraz6">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="">'+
        <param name="movie" value="">
    </object>
</div>
<div class="flashmoviecraz" id="flashmoviecraz7">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="">'+
        <param name="movie" value="">
    </object>
</div>
<div class="flashmoviecraz" id="flashmoviecraz8">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="">'+
        <param name="movie" value="">
    </object>
</div>
<div class="flashmoviecraz" id="flashmoviecraz9">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="">'+
        <param name="movie" value="">
    </object>
</div>
<div class="flashmoviecraz" id="flashmoviecraz10">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="">'+
        <param name="movie" value="">
    </object>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

Keep in mind I don't only have 10 flashs I plan on having like a couple thousand or something like that idk. So I would need a solution that would work with an ever expanding collection not something that only works withs with like 10 of them.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var paths = [
'swfs/#1%20(Special%20Japanese%20Extended%20Dance%20Mix).swf',
'swfs/$D6.swf',
'swfs/(MAD)%20Huh.swf',
'swfs/(^q^)冷やしくおえうえーーーるえうおおお%20FIXED.swf',
'swfs/(ﾉ＾∇＾)ﾉ☎------[](;￣Д￣).swf',
'swfs/-(。ヘ°).swf',
'swfs/-ppppSuperWiiUv5_2.swf',
'swfs/0x40%20Hues%20v4n20.swf',
'swfs/0x40%20Huеs%20of%20Winter.swf',
'swfs/10r.swf',
'swfs/1421379050663.swf'];

var a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j = 0;
    var flashmovie, flashmoviecraz1, flashmoviecraz2, flashmoviecraz3, flashmoviecraz4, flashmoviecraz5, flashmoviecraz6, flashmoviecraz7, flashmoviecraz8, flashmoviecraz9, flashmoviecraz10,
        test, temp, temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5, temp6, temp7, temp8, temp9, temp10;

    function craz() {
            flashmoviecraz1 = document.getElementById('flashmoviecraz1');
            flashmoviecraz2 = document.getElementById('flashmoviecraz2');
            flashmoviecraz3 = document.getElementById('flashmoviecraz3');
            flashmoviecraz4 = document.getElementById('flashmoviecraz4');
            flashmoviecraz5 = document.getElementById('flashmoviecraz5');
            flashmoviecraz6 = document.getElementById('flashmoviecraz6');
            flashmoviecraz7 = document.getElementById('flashmoviecraz7');
            flashmoviecraz8 = document.getElementById('flashmoviecraz8');
            flashmoviecraz9 = document.getElementById('flashmoviecraz9');
            flashmoviecraz10 = document.getElementById('flashmoviecraz10');

            window.onload = function () {
                temp1 = a;
                temp2 = b;
                temp3 = c;
                temp4 = d;
                temp5 = e;
                temp6 = f;
                temp7 = g;
                temp8 = h;
                temp9 = i;
                temp10 = j;

                while (a == temp1) {
                    a = Math.floor(Math.random() * paths.length);
                }
                while (b == temp2) {
                    b = Math.floor(Math.random() * paths.length);
                }
                while (c == temp3) {
                    c = Math.floor(Math.random() * paths.length);
                }
                while (d == temp4) {
                    d = Math.floor(Math.random() * paths.length);
                }
                while (e == temp5) {
                    e = Math.floor(Math.random() * paths.length);
                }
                while (f == temp6) {
                    f = Math.floor(Math.random() * paths.length);
                }
                while (g == temp7) {
                    g = Math.floor(Math.random() * paths.length);
                }
                while (h == temp8) {
                    h = Math.floor(Math.random() * paths.length);
                }
                while (i == temp9) {
                    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * paths.length);
                }
                while (j == temp10) {
                    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * paths.length);
                }

                flashmoviecraz1.innerHTML =
                    '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="' + paths[a] + '">' +
                    '<param name="movie" value="' + paths[a] + '">' +
                    '<\/object>';

                flashmoviecraz2.innerHTML =
                    '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="' + paths[b] + '">' +
                    '<param name="movie" value="' + paths[b] + '">' +
                    '<\/object>';

                flashmoviecraz3.innerHTML =
                    '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="' + paths[c] + '">' +
                    '<param name="movie" value="' + paths[c] + '">' +
                    '<\/object>';
                flashmoviecraz4.innerHTML =
                    '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="' + paths[d] + '">' +
                    '<param name="movie" value="' + paths[d] + '">' +
                    '<\/object>';
                flashmoviecraz5.innerHTML =
                    '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="' + paths[e] + '">' +
                    '<param name="movie" value="' + paths[e] + '">' +
                    '<\/object>';
                flashmoviecraz6.innerHTML =
                    '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="' + paths[f] + '">' +
                    '<param name="movie" value="' + paths[f] + '">' +
                    '<\/object>';
                flashmoviecraz7.innerHTML =
                    '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="' + paths[g] + '">' +
                    '<param name="movie" value="' + paths[g] + '">' +
                    '<\/object>';
                flashmoviecraz8.innerHTML =
                    '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="' + paths[h] + '">' +
                    '<param name="movie" value="' + paths[h] + '">' +
                    '<\/object>';
                flashmoviecraz9.innerHTML =
                    '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="' + paths[i] + '">' +
                    '<param name="movie" value="' + paths[i] + '">' +
                    '<\/object>';
                flashmoviecraz10.innerHTML =
                    '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="' + paths[j] + '">' +
                    '<param name="movie" value="' + paths[j] + '">' +
                    '<\/object>';
            };

        }
```

A picture of my failure :(

https://gyazo.com/1779a800c83fd8095e8f53ad88d6114e

(Don't hate just a test page)

Comment: You really should make a test link online so we see the problem in action. You can always delete the test page after you have a solution. Most likey the final HTML rendered by browser has invalid links to SWF files.

Answer (score 0):

Untested but just from looking, these things that could be a problem...

**1)** Try using full URLs in your array like `http://www.mysite/swfs/10r.swf`...

**2)** Try not having spaces `%20` in your file names, maybe use underscore like `(MAD)_Huh.swf`...

**3)** A line like `data="' + paths[b] + '"` should be seen as `data="swfs/$D6.swf"` in the view source after displaying HTML page. Since you gave no link to check, you check by yourself to make sure it's like that or you will get error `"move not loaded"` when you right-click on the white box (Flash).

Maybe instead of :

```
flashmoviecraz1.innerHTML =
                    '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="' + paths[b] + '">' +
                    '<param name="movie" value="' + paths[b] + '">' +
                    '<\/object>';
```

Try using it like this

```
flashmoviecraz1.innerHTML =
                    '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data=' + paths[b] + '>' +
                    '<param name="movie" value=' + paths[b] + '>' +
                    '<\/object>';
```

Comment: I corrected the innerhtml part but I still get the "movie not loaded" thing I know the file paths are correct bc they work on another page in the site that selects one randomly but only one at a time. Also I will implement the changes to the file paths that you have recommended the next time I update the array... haven't really done anything like this before so thank you for the tip :D. Still not working though QUICK EDIT the two html pages are located in the same folder so there should be no different path to the swf's